# CocoaPods Installing an older pod

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to work with Firebase Push Notifications and in some of the posts there was a discussion that an older version of FirebaseMessaging pod needs to be installed.

How do I install an older version of a pod?

I tried a bunch of different command line options but with no luck.

Specifically I am trying to install FirebaseMessagin 2.0.0

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

how about: `pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '= 2.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the version in your podfile.

```
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 2.0'
```

This means "any version up to 2.0" You could also completely lock it to 2.0 by using:

```
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '=2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked was putting in my Podfile - pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '= 2.0.0'